# The given path format not supported error when reading the file in C#

Tags: c#, string

I am trying to read  txt file in C# but having error that

> The given's path not supported

I have done this a lots of time in application. But I don't know what is the issue. Here is my code:

```
 var filePath = @"‪E:\P1.txt";

 string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
```

It **throws exception** that *path not supported*. What's the issue?

Comment: If I copy paste your code it gives me the same error, if I write myself exactly the same string it works. Weird. Try rewrite your filePath string?

Comment: Check the length of the file name - by the look of it it should be 9 - filename.Length = 10 - so there is a non-displaying character in there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's have a look (print out the `string` *dump*):

```
var filePath = @"‪E:\P1.txt";

Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
                          filePath.Select(c => $"'{c}' : 0x{(int)c:x4}")));
```

**Outcome:**

```
'‪' : 0x202a    <- LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING
'E' : 0x0045
':' : 0x003a
'\' : 0x005c
'P' : 0x0050
'1' : 0x0031
'.' : 0x002e
't' : 0x0074
'x' : 0x0078
't' : 0x0074
```

Can you see invisible `0x202a` (LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING) symbol at the very start of the string?

https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202a/index.htm

this symbol makes the path being *invalid*.

Comment: What should i do now?

Comment: @Umer: you have to remove the *invisible symbol*. If the path is hardcoded then you can try re-type it (at least `"E:` frafment)

Comment: Re-type resolved the issue. I have copied the file paths many time but this happened to me first time. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 6):

As shown below, your file path contains the non-displayable [Left-to-Right Embedding](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=202A) (LRE) Unicode character.

```
"\u202AE:\P1.txt"
```

If you just delete the line and write the path again, your problem will most likely be resolved.